# How to create a block title?

Tags: blocks

I created a block to home page,
the code is:
{{block type="catalog/product_new" column_count="6" products_count="12" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}

but the block title not show in the home page, 
[image: the block title not show in the page]

just has a '`<h3 class ="section-title padding-right"></h3>`' tag.
[image: h3]

And I found this code in the new.phtml template file:

```
<h3 class="section-title padding-right"><?php echo $this->getBlockName(); ?></h3>
```

why? how to display the block title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" column_count="6" products_count="12" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" block_name="New Products"}}
```

This is not in the default magento theme, but maybe it works.